# Assign value that represents the number of records (count) from SQL query to variable in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I would like to create a variable in C# that represents the number of records of a query.
I tested the query and works correct , returning the correct value.

```
SELECT Count(c.Cell_ID) AS CountOfCell_ID
FROM Cells AS c
HAVING (((Exists (SELECT 1
              FROM ΠΑΡΟΝΤΕΣ as cu
              WHERE c.Cell_ID = cu.CellID))=False));
```

This returns a number only.
I would like to assign that number(result) to a variable in c#.

First step is to write the following C# code in visual studio

```
int: CountValue;
cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr;
         cnn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = cnn;
            string query = "SELECT Count(c.Cell_ID) AS CountOfCell_ID FROM Cells AS c HAVING(((Exists(SELECT 1 FROM ΠΑΡΟΝΤΕΣ as cu WHERE c.Cell_ID = cu.CellID)) = False));";
```

what should i do next to assign the value contained in query to CountValue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar

Comment: Such a bizarre way of writing that sql..

Comment: This is the MS access SQL format, i just copy-paste it on post

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions. Use WHERE clause for regular conditions.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do next is execute the command, and read the value:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = cnn;
string query = "SELECT Count(c.Cell_ID) AS CountOfCell_ID FROM Cells AS c HAVING(((Exists(SELECT 1 FROM ΠΑΡΟΝΤΕΣ as cu WHERE c.Cell_ID = cu.CellID)) = False));";

    // Open connection
    cnn.Open();
    
    // Call command's ExcuteReader
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Your value is here
                    Console.Write("OrderID :" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
                }
    
               // close reader and connection
                reader.Close();
                cnn.Close();
```

Comment: i get error on line " OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();"

Comment: Command text was not set for the command object

Comment: I think ExecureScalar() is the correct way to go

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
private void DashBoard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // timer1.Start();

        string sql = null;
        sql = "SELECT Count(c.Cell_ID) AS CountOfCell_ID FROM Cells AS c HAVING(((Exists(SELECT 1 FROM ΠΑΡΟΝΤΕΣ as cu WHERE c.Cell_ID = cu.CellID)) = False));";

        try
     {
         cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr;
           
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            
            command.Connection = cnn;
            command= new OleDbCommand(sql, cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            command.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(" No of Rows " + count);
            cnn.Close();
      
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
     }
   

    }
```